# How to create gui (graphic user interface) for standalong binary executable file

Tags: user-interface, modelica, dymola

I have a model in Modelica language (platform: Dymola). Dymola creates a binary file of model during compiling/translation **(dymosim.exe)**. If binary code export licence is available then a binary file which is standalone representative of original dymola model is created. This can be run on any computer without Dymola licence.

Now, My question is how can I create Gui for around this executable file  with following requirements:-
1. It should be able to change in some input parameter values.
2. It should be able to get some output parameter values.

Now as background:-
dymosim.exe takes parameter values as input from text file **(dsin.txt)** and writes output in another text file **(dsres.txt)**

Specifically, if one has such binary executable which takes input from a text file and writes output in specific format (of which rules are known) to another text file; then what are some tools to create gui for it?

Comment: You could consider exporting your model from Dymola to a co-simulation FMU. This can then be controlled from e.g. Python using PyFMI and you can build a GUI on top of the Python code.

Comment: @ Rene Just Nielsen I will look into this. But ultimately could this result in a  .exe file with gui. I ask this because on, end user's side expectation is having a executable which when run opens a interface to enter some input parameter value; has a run button or similar to run actual model with given inputs and present corresponding outputs.

Comment: You can also look into PySimulator https://github.com/PySimulator/PySimulator

Answer (score 1):

Look into Dymola's embedded server support (DDE/OPC). Since you are using dymosim.exe, I believe you are using Windows so Dymola's restriction on only Visual Studio 32-bit code for embedded servers will be acceptable. (Most Modelica tools have similar embedded servers, but I don't think they are compatible.)

Answer (score 1):

Dymola dymosim.exe exports its time series results as `*.mat` files, you should be able to find tools/libraries to handle `*.mat` format in your GUI.

Also, dsin.txt has its own format, you can try to understand it first (try to find its comments) and then parse it, it's not a text file with random string and number columns.

Comment: Hi, I am aware of disn.txt and dsres.mat structure. What I actually don't know is how to create a gui so that I can manipulate parameter values in dsin.txt, then run dymosim.exe wrt new parameters and read dsres.mat/dsres.txt.

Comment: I think this is more of a coding issue then. You should probably look into the text/string parsing of the programming language you are using for the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

To use FMI standard is worth to consider in the co-simulation mode which means that a solver is included. Dymola allows to export model as FMU package (in Windows platform it is single DLL with some metadata, in Linux platform it is .SO library) and provides these functions worth to do your steps:

- *fmiSetReal()* will set a parameter value
- *fmiDoStep()*
- *fmiGetReal()* will get the variable value

You can call these functions directly, just unzip FMU package and find the DLL inside and link it directly to your application.
Or recommended way (we did it in our app): use [FMI Library](http://www.jmodelica.org/FMILibrary) providing general C API interacting with a FMU package and controling temporal structures the way you need.